# Is there a statistical comparison of Emacs vs Vim in number of key strokes for given tasks?

Tags: vim, emacs

Emacs just has shortcuts for everything and as such a given shortcut can take a few key presses. Vim has modes which reduce keys for given tasks because it's usually just one key. But then you have to switch between modes a lot. It's all very well speculating which of the two is more efficient, or giving our personal experience, but I am wondering if anyone has made a proper statistical study, given some text/code editing tasks to perform, how many key presses it takes to perform the task in Emacs and Vim. If anyone has spare time to kill, that might be a cool project to do. You could include other editors.

(May I encourage you to downvote the inevitable hilarious jokes that will follow mentioning of an editor.)

Comment: This keystroke counting from vim/emacs users is turning into a crazy obsession. Downvoting for being a useless question.

Comment: Useless to whom?

Comment: To everyone.

Comment: Meh! Just another version of the Emacs-vs-Vi death match. In anycase, both are highly customizable, so whose versions do you propose to compare?

Comment: Usenet is ----> that way.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a laugh before bed. That really is obsessive.

Comment: Yeah, why pollute a good holy war with facts?  Sheesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so .. just lets say "no" :)